# How can I add leading zeros between delimiters in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to convert a list of property id numbers that has a standard format of 0000-A-00000-00-00, where my worksheet has the various combinations of

- `1-A-123`
- `10-B-1234`

Ideally they would read as follows

- `0001-A-00123-0000-00`
- `0010-B-01234-0000-00`

I've tried using the custom number formatting but it doesn't like the letter in the middle of the number.  I didn't know if my only option was to break them apart and then put them back together again.

I would accept a solution that merely put the leading zeros at the front of the number, (max is 4 characters)  so the result could look like 0001-A-123

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mega-formula or VBA for this

To recut data in A1 to your desired outpu in B1

`=IFERROR(REPT("0",4-FIND("-",A1)+1)&LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)&"-"&MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-1,1)&"-"&REPT(0,5-LEN(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1))))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1))&"-0000-00","missing -")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to split them apart (into 3 pieces) then combine them back again using string functions.

Like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqyHjJ0rl5d1dHgxNFlNVWd2Njd2cDVBaEtwWGxfU1E

Answer (score 0):

Save the spreadsheet as a CSV, edit with a smart text editor (e.g., `vi`), and read back into Excel.